# Jquery get select option id

Tags: jquery

I have this select

```
<select name="clients[]" size="20" multiple="multiple" id="clients" style="min-width:275px;">
<option id="first">First</option>
<option id="second">Second</option>
<option id="third">Third</option> 
</select>
```

I am trying to get this alert box to show up when the id = first, I've tried

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($('#clients option:selected').val() == 'first'){
        alert('hi');
    }
});
```

but nothing appears...what am I doing wrong

Comment: do you want to trigger the alert when the user change the selection or on page load? (or maybe both cases)

Comment: The value is `First`, not `first`. But anyway, you have a **multiselect** element, so none of the options will be selected at page load.

Comment: Instead of `<option id="first">` (etc) use: `<option value="first">`

Comment: @Felix Kling: I don't get why you say that none of the options can be selected on page load. They could bring the attribute selected from server. Could you clarify that?

Comment: @Claudio: Right, it could be selected if the `selected` attribute is set (I did not think about that), but it isn't in this example. Anyways, I was only thinking about that the browser selects the first element if you have a "normal" select element.

Answer (score 1):

The value is `First`, not `first`. Since you did not provide a `value` attribute, the content of the `option` element is taken as value.

Be aware that you use a multiselect field. In this case, the browser won't select an element on page <sup>*****</sup>, so it only makes sense to test for `first` when the selection chages.

You have to check whether `First` is one of the selected elements:

```
$('#clients').change(function(){
      if($(this).children('option:selected').filter('#first').length) {
          alert('hi');
      }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/ET2wJ/)

Another option would be to properly set the `value` attribute instead of IDs and see whether the value is in the values array:

HTML:

```
<option value="first">First</option>
<option value="second">Second</option>
<option value="third">Third</option>
```

JS:

```
$('#clients').change(function(){
      if($.inArray("first", $(this).val()) != -1) {
          alert('hi');
      }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/ET2wJ/1/)

---

<sup>*****</sup>: In case you might set the `selected` attribute on some elements beforehand and want to run the  test on page load, you can simply trigger the change event by calling `.change()` on the select element.

Answer (score 0):

This code triggers an alert in case the select has `First` selected on document ready and also when the user changes the selection

```
$(function(){
   checkSelection();

   $('#clients').change(function(){
      checkSelection();
   })

   function checkSelection(){
       var selectedOptions = $('#clients').val();

       if($.inArray('First',selectedOptions) != -1){
           alert('hi'); 
       }
   }  
})
```

Comment: The ID of element is `clients`, not `clients[]`. Also note that it is a multiselect element, so `val()` is probably returning an array.

Answer (score 0):

You've set the option ids instead of values in the html. Also, in jQuery to find the selected value, you only need to look for the value of the select element.

Do this instead:

```
<option value="first">First</option>
<option value="second">Second</option>
<option value="third">Third</option> 

$(document).ready(function(){
    if($('#clients').val() == 'first'){
        alert('hi');
    }
});
```

if you want it to show the popup in real time do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#clients').change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == 'first'){
      alert('hi');
    }
  });
});
```